# Django ManyToMany field gives IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django 2.1.2

I am having 2 Models `Items` and `Quotation`.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.name

class Quotation(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit_rate = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.company.company_name
```

Now when I am adding Item it is working correctly.

But when I try to add quotation in Admin Panel, it gives me `null value in column "item_id" violates not-null constraint`

I am new to Django. It would be great if someone can point what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you might have changed `Quotation.item` from a `ForeignKey` or `OneToOneField` to a `ManyToManyField` field.

After making this change, you have to run `manage.py makemigrations` and then `manage.py migrate` to create and then run the necessary database migrations. Note that any existing data in the `Quotation.item_id` column will be deleted unless you write migrations to copy the data to the many-to-many field.

Comment: Previously it was OneToOne and then I changed it to ManyToMany. But I deleted all the previous entries of quotation and tried with new one.

Comment: Deleted old migration also. and tried makemigrations and migrate too

Comment: Deleting existing quotations isn’t required. The migration is required to drop the old column and create the joining table for the many-to-many field.

Comment: You shouldn’t delete migrations unless you have a really good reason to. Now your migrations and database are out of sync, which is tricky to fix. If you are in development and don’t have any important data in the database, then your easiest option is to delete the migrations, drop and recreate the database (just delete the sqlite file if you are using sqlite), then make new migrations and run them.

Comment: Running sync db wont help after deleting migration ? I am not into development

Comment: No, `syncdb` won’t help, it is an old command that was replaced by migrations.

Comment: So only option is to delete database ?

Comment: The other option is to compare the database schema and the migration files, and then manually alter your database to sync it with your migrations. For example, you would have to drop the `item_id` column, but there might be other steps required as well. This can be a tricky process which I can't help you with.

Comment: I deleted Database, I will update you in sometime if its working or not

Comment: It’s too late for you now, but another option would have been to restore the original migration files (e.g. from backups or your git repository), then try running makemigrations and migrate as in my original answer. If you aren’t currently backing up you migrations and keeping them in source control then make sure you start doing this, they are as important as your code.

Comment: I do add migrations to source control. That was a great tip. After droping the database, now everything seems fine. But now I am a bit afraid to try new things because db might break. and I have to spend days solving this

Comment: Can you update your answer with droping db option so I can accept your answer.

Comment: I'd rather not put dropping the database in the answer itself, because it should be a last resort. If you hadn't deleted the migrations, then running `makemigrations` and then `migrate` should have worked.

Comment: I tried makemigrations and migrate before that but nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me too recently while working on a client project. Guess what, the client developer forgot to make migrations after modifying a model in Django.

This error usually occurs because of DB. You can check the table details in DB to make sure that the field you're passing null value to is actually nullable or not.

eg. in Postgres - `\d table_name`;

How I solved it?

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. `python manage.py migrate`